# Minimum number of "ready" IIS worker processes

Tags: iis, performance, worker-process

In my experience working with IIS, when a worker process is recycled, the next request to "activate" the new process has to wait whilst the process performs it's one-time startup. This wait can be particularly bad when programs are doing quite large application startups.

Is there a way through IIS to keep a minimum number of worker processes in a "ready" state, so they will serve requests immediately? I still want worker processes to be recycled, but for them not to serve requests until they're in a "ready" state, so users don't feel the startup cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 7.5 (Windows Server 2008 R2) you can use the **startMode** property to ask the App Pool to boot even without a request coming in. By default, they're still demand-started (at least, so says the documentation), but adding this attribute to an applicationPool should allow it to noodle around happily, even while idle.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689467(v=VS.90).aspx

I agree with rfair01 though, in that it's probably a better idea not to have them recycle in the first place; this isn't always feasible, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different things you can do:

1) Change your app pool so that it does not automatically recycle.  This will keep your application ready at all times unless IIS is restarted.  If you are in a shared hosting situation, this may not be practical.  If you have memory issues with the application, this may not be a good approach either.

2) Use a scheduled warmup script.  If app pools are on a schedule to recycle, you can create a script that will hit a page on your site to warm up the app pool.  Example [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/steveschofield/archive/2006/09/28/Schedule-a-task-to-call-a-webpage-using-Task-scheduler_2E00_.aspx).  That way your application should be ready to respond quickly to requests.